# Interaction plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, interaction

I want from the following dataset:

```
ID  Result Days Position   
1   70     0    1     
1   80     23   1
2   90     15   2
2   89     30   2
2   99     40   2
3   23     24   1
etc...
```

To make 2 spaghetti plots: 1 for those who are in position 1 and one for those in position 2. I tried a "for & if" loop, but I just got the mixed plot many times. Also I am using  `ggplot`.

```
dfPr <- df[df$Progress==1]
 x11()
 ggplot(dfPr, aes(x=OrderToFirstBx, y=result.num, color=factor(MRN))) +
 geom_line() + theme_bw() + xlab("Time in Days") + ylab("ALT")
```

This worked! But if you have another solution please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=stats/man/interaction.plot.Rd&d=R_rel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave such limited example data, and your sample code doesn't seem to match the variable names in your sample data which make it very hard to tell exactly what you wanted.

If you want two separate plots, using facets might be the easiest. Try

```
#sample data
dfPr <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Result = c(70L, 
80L, 90L, 89L, 99L, 23L), Days = c(0L, 23L, 15L, 30L, 40L, 24L
), Position = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("ID", "Result", 
"Days", "Position"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

ggplot(dfPr, aes(x=Days, y=Result, group=ID)) + 
    geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Position)
```